# Delete entry from HSTS list in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11, hsts

I'm struggling with this issue for a while and I don't seem to find any answer.

Do you know if there's any way to delete an entry from the HSTS list in Internet Explorer 11?

I'm looking for something similar with chrome's "chrome://net-internals/#hsts".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not aware of a way, though if you have access to the server config you can just set max-age to 0 then reload the HTTPS site in IE11, which will remove it.

Alternatively Microsoft shows how you can turn HSTS off completely (for **all sites** in IE11) in the registry (not recommended as it is a good feature but maybe a last resort): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3071338. Could also have a hunt around in that registry area to see if you can find the policy for your particular site (not sure if this is stored in registry or not to be honest).